# Can package objects have an apply method in scala?

Tags: scala

In Scala, is is possible to define an apply method inside a package object and use the package object like a function?

For instance, I define my package object to be:

```
package io.foo

package object f {
   def apply[X](x: X): String = x.toString
}
```

And then, in some other file, I want to use it like this:

```
import io.foo._

val s = f(5)
```

However, when you do this, you'll get a compile error saying  `package io.foo.f is not a value`

The following compiles though:

```
import io.foo._

val s = f.apply(5)
```

Also, is there any drawback in doing this?